# Why android:gravity attribute for ImageView is not there?

Tags: android

Does anybody know, why there is no android:gravity attribute for ImageView?
Why only android:layout_gravity is shown by Eclipse?

Answer (score 3):

> Does anybody know, why there is no android:gravity attribute for ImageView?

Because the developer of `ImageView` decided not to create one. Not every attribute is used for every widget. In this case, `ImageView` instead [uses `android:scaleType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType) to control how the image fits in the space devoted to the `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

`android:gravity` is used to set the gravity to the content inside the `View`, whereas `android:layout_gravity` sets the gravity of the `View` relative to its parent.

I think an `ImageView` does not need `android:gravity` because it should not have child content.

Comment: Not agree. If u say ImageView should not have child content,then how should TextView has child content? As android:gravity is there on TextView.

Comment: But if you try to put child content both on `ImageView` and `TextView`, you get a `ClassCastException`, because those widgets cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup. Also, in which case would you need to add child content to a TextView? If you need to add an image to the text, then you should use a compound drawable instead.

Comment: I'm just asking, I don't want to start a war here hehe :P